# Invalid type error for REST function call

Tags: magento2

I have a method in my Interface which im trying to call using REST.

**in webapi.xml**

```
<route url="/V1/sync/get/sku:sku" method="GET">                                   
    <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\QueueRepositoryInterface" method="myMethod"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

In Api/QueueRepositoryInterface.php

```
interface QueueRepositoryInterface
{
   /**
 * Returns single product by SKU.
 *
 * @api
 * @param int $sku
 * @return
 */
 public function myMethod($sku);
}
```

Is my param in the comment right?

Cause when i hit (sku_test2 : is my SKU)

```
http://localhost/magento/rest/V1/sync/get/sku/sku_test2
```

I get

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
  <message>Invalid type for value: "sku". Expected Type: "int".</message>
</response>
```

Comment: If 'sku_test2' is your sku, then you shouldn't declare the @param as an int - try it with a string type (or you could change your url structure to just pass the 2). The php docblock informs Magento what type to expect, so you've told it to expect an int, and given it a string.